# Store Custom Data on item in Woocommerce Cart

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm developing a gift card system, and we're using the [woocommerce smart coupons plugin](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/smart-coupons/). When users order a gift card, they can add the name of who it's to, as well as a message to be sent to the recipient with the gift card.

The problem is, smart coupons only stores the recipient's email and message.

The approach I took at first is to store the recipient data in the $woocommerce->session, which works for showing the data in the cart/checkout.. but after they finish checking out, the session is cleared and the data isn't available in the email that's sent out.

I've also been trying to add the data as $cart_item_data when I add the cards to cart.

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($gift_card_id, 1, $var_id, $attributes[$x], array("card_recipient_info" => $recipient_info[$x]));
```

However, for some reason the $cart_item_data isn't available in the cart on the front end..

What I want is to be able to store some data on the gift card when they add to cart, and be able to access it after they checkout. I have a feeling there's an easy way to do this that I'm just missing..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thank you.

Comment: [Product Add-Ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) will do this for you.

Comment: http://sarkware.com/how-to-pass-custom-data-to-cart-line-item-in-woocommerce-without-using-plugins